# Spring Boot Actuator endpoints not exposed in application without controller

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I have created a Spring Boot Application which starts streaming a large set of data on a Kafka Queue. It does not have a Controller as I don't have any endpoints, but I want the Actuator endpoints to be visible. Is it required to always have a Controller in order that the Actuator endpoints are visible. I have followed all the steps to setup the actuator endpoints.
This is the repository: https://github.com/gavarava/postgres-big-db

Answer (score 1):

No , you don't need to have any `controller` to use `actuators`.
The reason your actuator endpoints not showing up is you have not added actuator dependency in your `pom.xml`.
Add this in your `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

This will give you `health` and `info` endpoints.
If you want all endpoints add this property in your `application.properties` file.

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

You will be access the endpoints at `/actuator/{endpoint}`.
You will find more on actuators at
https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-features.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. Check my own answer...still learning the exact way spring starts everything.

Comment: You have finally added actuator dependency. Actuator dependency was not in your pom.xml when you asked your question.

Comment: Yeah it was not working inspite of adding the dependency. So it worked in my tests, but not in production. Difference was I had disabled the Kafka producer in test profile. Thanks for the support.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was creating a Kafka producer with a semi infinite loop.
So it seems like Spring Initialization would not finish enabling actuator endpoints, as my semi-infinite loop was going on forward.
I changed the while loop to an if condition and called it every 5 seconds, also added an Async annotation to my method.

That way everything moves on and actuator is enabled too.